# Deleting Files with c#

Tags: c#, error-handling, delete-file

I´m making a program to delete some files that I have on my PC. But when I try to do it, I get some error messages like this:

> If you are attempting to access a file, make sure it is not ReadOnly.
>
> Make Sure you have sufficient privileges to access this resource.
>
> Get general Help for this exception.

```
    foreach (string subFich in SubFicheiros)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add("- Deleting File: " + subFich.Substring(Pasta.Length + 1, subFich.Length - Pasta.Length - 1));
        ficheirosEncontrador++;
    }
    try
    {
        Directory.Delete(Pasta, true);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    //The Message Error appears here on this code right below:
            Directory.Delete(Pasta, true);

    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        Directory.Delete(Pasta, true);
    }
}
```

I would like to get some help with this.
How do i ask the user, to let me get the privilegies to delete it.

Comment: You repeat the `Directory.Delete()` command in the `try` and `catch` blocks. It should only be in the `try` block. Privileges are set outside of your program by the administrator on the PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. what your code doing is: You're deleting the directory and if it gives any exception then you're again trying to do the same step where you got exception.

First of all error is because files are set to read only or because you dont have enough rights to delete the directory (or probably some process is using the files which you are trying to delete)

```
 foreach (string subFich in SubFicheiros)
{
    listBox.Items.Add("- Deleting File: " + subFich.Substring(Pasta.Length + 1, subFich.Length - Pasta.Length - 1));
    ficheirosEncontrador++;
}
try
{
var di = new DirectoryInfo(Pasta);
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
 Directory.Delete(Pasta, true);
}
catch (Exception EE)
{

 MessageBox.Show("Error: "+ EE.toString());
}
```

if this code still doesn't work check if you have admin rights to delete that folder

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your file is read-only, or you do not have the right to remove the file you want based on your user login.